# Optimize logstash configuration to reduce CPU utilization

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Currently my filter looks like :

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => {
                "message" => '%{SYSLOG5424SD:logLevel}\t<%{JAVACLASS:Job} *>\t%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Date}\t%{GREEDYDATA:kvmessage}'
        }
    }
    if ([message] !~ "LogstashEvent") {
         drop { }
     }
    grok {
        match => {
                "kvmessage" => '%{SYSLOG5424SD}%{GREEDYDATA:kvmess}'
        }
    }
    kv {
        source => "kvmess"
        field_split => "|"
    }
}
```

I am taking input from lot of files using the input filter. At its max it could be **around 6000** files. But out of the huge number of logs generated, the logs I am interested in are just the one's with *"LogstashEvent"* in them - which will be even less than 1% of the total logs. I am guessing there has to be faster ways of doing this than what I am doing now. Right now CPU utilization of logstash is about 20% which is very high than what I expected it to be - considering my filter is not huge (although volume of input is)

Also I generated `kvmessage` above to use it in the second grok. I don't really need that finally. Is there anyway to drop mappings?

A dummy log illustrating the kind of logs I am trying to analyze here :

> [INFO]     2016-06-28 17:20:49,308 [LogstashEvent]a=1|b=talkischeap|c=showmecode|d=24|e=0

Is it possible that the CPU utilization of logstash on each of my host is high because my elascticsearch cluster is not able to index it fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this:

```
if ([message] !~ "LogstashEvent") {
    drop { }
}
```

before the first grok filter. You'll save your first grok filter 99% of its previous work.

You can drop fields with the remove_field` option, which is present in all filters. ([drop_field option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-remove_field))

And I don't think the indexing speed has a negative impact. When elasticsearch can't index fast enough for logstash, logstash will wait for it and stop reading the files.

Comment: Oh! I thought logstash never waits! So how long will it wait? Suppose my es cluster's memory is filled and I delete an index after say an hour of the time that the memory got filled..so it will wait for an hour?

Comment: I have observed that when logstash can't reach one output (in my case because an ES cluster was down), it waits until it can resume outputting (observed in version 1.5, but I think it's the case with other versions).   
So yes it will wait for one hour in your case.
You'll have to take a look at the documentation for more details about that.

Comment: Will see ..will not want it to wait though. Hope there is an option to specify that just drop the logs if es cluster is inactive. Whenever my cluster is up again I would want the recent logs...not logs from an hour before!

Comment: Apparently the number of retries depends on the version. You'll have to check the documentation for that, I can't help you any further